# Iterate over dataframe rows and assign to list based on variable in list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which is this -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qcQRwmFIkTJHPaknXjV1vNlDScw1Fxf6/view?usp=sharing

```
 Kyphosis  Age  Number  Start  prob_Age  prob_Number  prob_Start
50   absent   68       5     10  0.993964     0.208729    0.916693
51   absent    9       2     17  0.997321     0.904427    0.047178
52  present  139      10      6  0.004772     0.001366    0.964974
53   absent    2       2     17  0.997710     0.904427    0.047178
54   absent  140       4     15  0.004711     0.779213    0.072759
55   absent   72       5     15  0.993830     0.208729    0.072759
56   absent    2       3     13  0.997710     0.829827    0.090356
57  present  120       5      8  0.005786     0.208729    0.939803
58   absent   51       7      9  0.994754     0.072175    0.927241
59   absent  102       3     13  0.006362     0.829827    0.090356
60  present  130       4      1  0.005290     0.779213    0.996493
61  present  114       7      8  0.006029     0.072175    0.939803
62   absent   81       4      1  0.993617     0.779213    0.996493
63   absent  118       3     16  0.005872     0.829827    0.060197
64   absent  118       4     16  0.005872     0.779213    0.060197
65   absent   17       4     10  0.996844     0.779213    0.916693
66   absent  195       2     17  0.001558     0.904427    0.047178
67   absent  159       4     13  0.003517     0.779213    0.090356
68   absent   18       4     11  0.996783     0.779213    0.909644
69   absent   15       5     16  0.996966     0.208729    0.060197
70   absent  158       5     14  0.003580     0.208729    0.083307
71   absent  127       4     12  0.005449     0.779213    0.092836
72   absent   87       4     16  0.993547     0.779213    0.060197
73   absent  206       4     10  0.001135     0.779213    0.916693
74   absent   11       3     15  0.997205     0.829827    0.072759
75   absent  178       4     15  0.002387     0.779213    0.072759
76  present  157       3     13  0.003643     0.829827    0.090356
77   absent   26       7     13  0.996282     0.072175    0.090356
78   absent  120       2     13  0.005786     0.904427    0.090356
79  present   42       7      6  0.995277     0.072175    0.964974
80   absent   36       4     13  0.995648     0.779213    0.090356
```

and I have these kinds of the list :

```
A=0,S=0,N=0
X3=[A,S]
X7=[N,A,A,A,S,S]
X5=[S,N,A,A,S,A,S]
X4=[N,S,N,A,A,S,A,S]
X9=[N,S,N,A,A,S,A,S]
X10=[A,A,A,S,S]
list=[ X7,  X7,  X5,  X7,  X7,  X7,  X7,  X5,  X7,  X7,  X5,  X5,  X3,  X7,  X7,  X7, X10, X10,  X7,  X7, X10,  X7,  X7, X10,  X7, X10,  X9,  X7,  X7,  X4,X7]
```

Now, what I aim to do is to go through the df, put the values of column 
'prob_Age' 'prob_Number' 'prob_Start' of each record respectively into the 'list'

I tried this code :

```
A=0,S=0,N=0
X3=[N,A,S]
X7=[A,S]
X5=[A,S]
X4=[N,A,S]
X9=[A,A,S]
X10=[A,A,S]
list=[ X7,  X7,  X5,  X7,  X7,  X7,  X7,  X5,  X7,  X7,  X5,  X5,  X3,  X7,  X7,  X7, X10, X10,  X7,  X7, X10,  X7,  X7, X10,  X7, X10,  X9,  X7,  X7,  X4,X7]
list1=[]
for i in df.iterrows():
    A=df['prob_Age']
    S=df['prob_Number']
    N=df['prob_Start']
    print(list)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
list=[ [0.993964,0.916693],  [0.997321,0.047178],  [0.004772,0.964974],  [0.997710,0.047178],  [0.004711,0.072759], 
      [0.993830,0.072759],  [0.997710,0.090356],  [0.005786,0.939803],  [0.994754,0.927241],  [0.006362,0.090356],  
      [0.005290,0.996493],  [0.006029,0.939803],  [0.993617,0.779213,0.996493],  [0.005872,0.060197],  [0.005872,0.060197],
      [0.996844,0.916693], [0.001558,0.001558,0.047178], [0.003517,0.090356],  [ 0.996783,0.909644],  [0.996966,0.060197], 
      [0.003580,0.003580,0.083307],  [0.005449,0.092836],  [0.993547,0.060197], [0.001135,0.001135,0.916693], [0.997205,0.072759], 
      [ 0.002387,0.002387,0.072759],  [0.003643,0.003643 ,0.090356],  [0.996282 ,0.090356],  [0.005786,0.090356],  [0.995277,0.072175,0.964974],[0.995648,0.090356]]
```

I got the answer thankyou all :

```
list=[]
c=0
for _, x in df.iterrows():
    A, S, N = x[['prob_Age', 'prob_Start', 'prob_Number']].values
    X3=[N,A,S]
    X7=[A,S]
    X5=[A,S]
    X4=[N,A,S]
    X9=[A,A,S]
    X10=[A,A,S]
    l=[ X7,  X7,  X5,  X7,  X7,  X7,  X7,  X5,  X7,  X7,  X5,  X5,  X3,  X7,  X7,  X7, X10, X10,  X7,  X7, X10,  X7,  X7, X10,  X7, X10,  X9,  X7,  X7,  X4, X7]
    list.append(l[c])
    c=c+1
print(list)
```

Comment: Show the df here please. Cant download/look at the file on google drive.

Comment: @Sid i have done it :).

Comment: Expected output has only two numbers in the first list item? Is this because the record is missing or?

Comment: no, nothing is missing, see it's like this--- the first item of the list is X7 and X7 have [A, S] and this A=df['prob_Age'] =0.993964 & S=df['prob_Start'] =0.916693  ----- the Second item of the list is also X7 and X7 have [A, S] and this A=df['prob_Age'] =0.997321 & S=df['prob_Start'] =0.047178,

Comment: the value of A & S depends on the Which record  you are on @Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `list` is a built-in function in python, so you shouldn't really use it as variable name. Second, although you're changing vars A, S, N in each iteration (well not really changing because in each iteration you're assigning them same values), you're not changing the values of any of the lists. So to get your wanted output for each iteration you should do something like this:

```
for _, x in df.iterrows():
    A, S, N = x[['prob_Age', 'prob_Number', 'prob_Start']].values
    X3=[N,A,S]
    X7=[A,S]
    X5=[A,S]
    X4=[N,A,S]
    X9=[A,A,S]
    X10=[A,A,S]
    l=[ X7,  X7,  X5,  X7,  X7,  X7,  X7,  X5,  X7,  X7,  X5,  X5,  X3,  X7,  X7,  X7, X10, X10,  X7,  X7, X10,  X7,  X7, X10,  X7, X10,  X9,  X7,  X7,  X4,X7]
    print(l)
```

Now that being said, depending what your end goal here is, i'm pretty sure that there is better solution.

**EDIT**
This might be a bit better:

```
inds = [
    'X7', 'X7', 'X5', 'X7', 'X7', 'X7', 'X7', 'X5', 'X7', 'X7',
    'X5', 'X5', 'X3', 'X7', 'X7', 'X7', 'X10', 'X10', 'X7', 'X7',
    'X10', 'X7', 'X7', 'X10', 'X7', 'X10', 'X9', 'X7', 'X7', 'X4', 'X7'
]
def fill_in(idx, row):
    A, S, N = row[['prob_Age', 'prob_Number', 'prob_Start']].values
    d = {
        'X3': [N,A,S],
        'X7': [A,S],
        'X5': [A,S],
        'X4': [N,A,S],
        'X9': [A,A,S],
        'X10': [A,A,S]
    }
    return d[inds[idx]]

l = [fill_in(i, x) for i, x in df.iterrows()]
```

Comment: I think the `l` will get rewritten with every iteration.

Comment: Isn't that what OP wants?

Comment: Sorry about that, just re-read the question. I think you are right. I assumed he wanted the first row to give `X7` values and then subsequent rows to give value as per the list variable.

Comment: @RaskoVučinić each required value is getting printed for 31 times like this:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fzYP71wZjprDfhDotNZw5RTZFYh38N2l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Adarshsingh can you clarify what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @RaskoVučinić hey I changed few things and got the answer, thank you,  your code helped a noob :), I have  edited the question and added  the solution you can see

Comment: @RaskoVučinić hey yes that's a better way to do it, thanks to you \(^.^)/ I used a very lame approach :/ but your's seems cooler and I think I must stop using the list as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to do it.

```
#A=0,S=0,N=0 This is not required
#X3=[N,A,S]
#X7=[A,S]
#X5=[A,S]
#X4=[N,A,S]
#X9=[A,A,S]
#X10=[A,A,S]
l =[ 'X7',  'X7',  'X5',  'X7',  'X7',  'X7',  'X7',  'X5'........]
# as pointed out above list should not be used as a variable
# change l values into string, there are easy ways to do this.
idx = 0

for i,row in df.iterrows():    # have to add the row because there are two values index and row to unpack
   A=row['prob_Age']
   S=row['prob_Number']
   N=row['prob_Start']
   X3=[N,A,S]
   X7=[A,S]
   X5=[A,S]
   X4=[N,A,S]
   if str(list[idx]) == 'X7':   # the str part is not required if the l is changed.
        list[idx] = X7
   elif str(list[idx]) == 'X3':
        list[idx] = X3
   elif str(list[idx]) == 'X5':
        list[idx] = X5
   elif str(list[idx]) == 'X4':
        list[idx] = X4
    ### Put more conditions
   idx +=1
```

Comment: hey @Sid sorry I didn't get the answer from this code, I guess I failed to explain it to you in right way btw I have edited the question with the answer, you can see

Comment: @Adarshsingh good on you for figuring out the code and cobbling together the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely clear but if I have understood correctly, and you want a list of each list (val 1, val 2, val 3) per row, this will work. I mocked up a similar df ('data' in the example: https://imgur.com/a/MhTuUbh) to test it.

```
list_to_fill = []

length = len(data)

row = 0
col = 4
cell = data.iat[row, col]

for r in range (length):

    temp_row_list = []
    for i in range(3):
        cell = data.iat[row, col]
        temp_row_list.append(cell)
        col = col + 1    
    list_to_fill.append(temp_row_list)

    col = 4
    row = row + 1

print ('final list =', list_to_fill)
```

giving you:

final list = [[4, 5, 1], [7, 3, 2], [9, 0, 8]]